# Microsoft Graph API: Add row returns error

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to insert a row into an Office 365 Excel Sheet using Microsoft Graph.

Im POSTing

```
{
  "values": "[[1, 2],[4, 5]]"
}
```

to

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<mydocumentid>/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/Table1/rows/`

as per "Example 1" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-post-rows?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I get Bad Request 400 returned:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "invalidArgument",
            "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
            "date": "2023-07-19T16:17:33",
            "request-id": "<request-id>",
            "client-request-id": "<client-request-id>"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what argument is invalid, missing or incorrectly formatted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in the documentation. POST works if the quotes are removed from the "values" value.

Comment: Several issues reported but the doc still not fixed: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%225787d91b-2b8d-3a44-e2ec-475909e682ed%22&in=body